# Use Prestashop module tpl variable inside product page

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have a Prestashop module built that enable me upload additional images for each product. By using hook, The image is displayed on the product page using the hook {hook h='displayProductAdditionalInfo' product=$product}. See the module tpl code below:

```
{if $images}
    {foreach from=$images item=image}
        {if $image.type ==1}
            <img src="{$this_path}uploads/{$image.image}" width="">
        {else}
            <img src="{$this_path}uploads/{$image.image}" width="">
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

The challenge I have is that I want to use one of this image as background image for a section my poduct.tpl file. For example, using the code below:

```
<div class="uk-background-cover uk-panel" style="background-image: url(...);">
{block name='page_header'}
   <h1 class="h1" itemprop="name">{block name='page_title'}{$product.name} 
    {/block}</h1>
{/block}
</div>
```

I thought of using `{assign var=bgpath value="{hook='displayProductAdditionalInfo'}"}` and then using it `{$bgpath}` inside `style="background-image: url({$bgpath});` but it brought errror.
I also tried below so that I can use `style="background-image: url({$bgpath});`:

```
{if $images}
        {foreach from=$images item=image}
            {if $image.type ==1}
                {assign var=bgpath value="{$this_path}uploads/{$image.image}"
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
{/if}
```

It didn't work because this variables are not available in product.tpl but in the module.tpl

I read that we may use controller override but I am not sure if it will work or how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use style tag instead of style attribute in your tpl file.

```
{if $images}
    {foreach from=$images item=image}
        {if $image.type ==1}
            {assign var=bgpath value="{$this_path}uploads/{$image.image}"
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
<style>
    div.uk-background-cover {
        background-image: url({$bgpath});
    }
</style>
{/if}
```